# Сортировка объектов в списке

Tags: java, сортировка

Есть список файлов, каждый назван по правилу 0.название, 1.название, 2.название и так до 25.
Имена всех этих файлов содержатся в списке `ArrayList` типа `String`, если вывести список на экран, то получаем:
0.название, 1.название, 10.название, 11.название - Почему? И как их можно отсортировать, чтобы они шли в порядке возрастнаия цифр?

```
 {
       //Получаю имена всех файлов в каталоге
       File dir = new File("resources\\Blocks\\");
       List<String> list = Arrays.asList(dir.list(new FilenameFilter()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".txt");
        }
   }
               
));
```

Вывод: `[0.Player Block.txt, 1.Sign.txt, 10.Beacon.txt, 11.Mob spawner.txt, 12.Music block.txt, 13.dgfd.txt, 14.Piston.txt, 15.Enchanting table.txt, 16.End portal block.txt, 17.End chest.txt, 18.Head.txt, 19.Command block.txt, 2.Flag.txt, 20.End gate block.txt, 21.Day light sensor.txt, 22.Flower pot.txt, 23.Komparator.txt, 24.Bed.txt, 25.Hive.txt, 3.Chest.txt, 4.Chest-trap.txt, 5.Dispenser.txt, 6.Furnace.txt, 7.Brewing stand.txt, 8.Shulker chest.txt, 9.Hopper.txt]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию строки сортируются в лексикографическом порядке согласно таблице `Unicode`. Вам необходимо написать свой `Comparator`. Ниже приведен очень простой пример. Но стоит учитывать, что указанный `Comparator` не является высокопроизводительным и написан только для примера.

```
package com.somepackage;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list =
                Stream.of(
                        "0.Player Block.txt",
                        "1.Sign.txt",
                        "10.Beacon.txt",
                        "11.Mob spawner.txt",
                        "12.Music block.txt",
                        "13.dgfd.txt",
                        "14.Piston.txt",
                        "15.Enchanting table.txt",
                        "16.End portal block.txt",
                        "17.End chest.txt",
                        "18.Head.txt",
                        "19.Command block.txt",
                        "2.Flag.txt",
                        "20.End gate block.txt",
                        "21.Day light sensor.txt",
                        "22.Flower pot.txt",
                        "23.Komparator.txt",
                        "24.Bed.txt",
                        "25.Hive.txt",
                        "3.Chest.txt",
                        "4.Chest-trap.txt",
                        "5.Dispenser.txt",
                        "6.Furnace.txt",
                        "7.Brewing stand.txt",
                        "8.Shulker chest.txt",
                        "9.Hopper.txt"
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> sortedList =
                list.stream()
                        .sorted((o1, o2) -> {
                            String[] tokens1 = o1.split("\\.");
                            String[] tokens2 = o2.split("\\.");

                            int prefix1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens1[0]);
                            int prefix2 = Integer.parseInt(tokens2[0]);

                            if (prefix1 != prefix2)
                                return prefix1 - prefix2;

                            String postfix1 = tokens1[1];
                            String postfix2 = tokens2[1];

                            return postfix1.compareToIgnoreCase(postfix2);
                        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(
                String.join("\n", sortedList));
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
0.Player Block.txt
1.Sign.txt
2.Flag.txt
3.Chest.txt
4.Chest-trap.txt
5.Dispenser.txt
6.Furnace.txt
7.Brewing stand.txt
8.Shulker chest.txt
9.Hopper.txt
10.Beacon.txt
11.Mob spawner.txt
12.Music block.txt
13.dgfd.txt
14.Piston.txt
15.Enchanting table.txt
16.End portal block.txt
17.End chest.txt
18.Head.txt
19.Command block.txt
20.End gate block.txt
21.Day light sensor.txt
22.Flower pot.txt
23.Komparator.txt
24.Bed.txt
25.Hive.txt
```

Вы также можете посмотреть соотвествующие обсуждения на английском языке:

- [Sort on a string that may contain a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104599/sort-on-a-string-that-may-contain-a-number)
- [How to sort a string list consists of digits and alphabets in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54026739/how-to-sort-a-string-list-consists-of-digits-and-alphabets-in-java)
- [Sorting Strings that contains number in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973503/sorting-strings-that-contains-number-in-java)

Comment: Хоть он и не является высокопроизводительным, для моих нужд его вполне хватает и он прекрасно работает. Спасибо вам большое

Answer (score 0):

Так уж сортируются строки по умолчанию.

Чтобы отсортировать иначе - надо применять Comparator. Например как-то так:

```
listOfStrings.sort((s1, s2) -> Integer.valueOf(s1.split(".").get(0))- Integer.valueOf(s2.split(".").get(0)));
```